# Accurate benchmark of battery usage of Android application

Tags: android, benchmarking, power-management

I am trying to benchmark the battery/CPU usage of an Android application I have developed vs the battery usage of another third party application. The applications almost perform the same type of tasks, so I am trying to measure the efficiency of both applications in terms of battery/CPU usage.

When I try to measure the battery usage through the Android settings interface, it shows me a bunch of other processes that are already consuming the Battery. My current battery usage stats are:

Screen 55%
Android System 14%
Cell Standby 9%
Android OS 7%
Launcher 4%
Phone Idle 3%

Is there anyway I can reduce the battery usage of these components, in order to reduce the error of margin when measuring the battery usage of the Android applications? I have already cleared all running applications, disabled some pre-installed applications such as GMail, Calendar etc.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there anyway I can reduce the battery usage of these components, in order to reduce the error of margin when measuring the battery usage of the Android applications?

If neither app requires the Internet, put the device in airplane mode.

Also, if you do not want "Screen" to swamp the rest of the data, you will need to allow the screen to go dark.

Note that the "battery blame" screen's data source uses some heuristics to try to apportion the battery consumption, and those heuristics are a bit better than guesswork, but not by much.